# Joining 3 tables and using WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables:-

users (username, business_id, etc.)

businesses (business_id, service_type, latitude, longitude, etc.)

addresses (address_id, country_iso, etc.)

And I have the following query which works fine:

```
SELECT username, users.business_id, businesses.latitude, businesses.longitude
FROM users
JOIN businesses 
ON users.business_id = businesses.business_id
WHERE service_type = ?
```

Now, I also want to filter the results by a "country_iso" value (a column in the 'addresses' table).

I tried to do the following but I get an error:

```
SELECT username, users.business_id, businesses.latitude, businesses.longitude 
FROM users
JOIN businesses 
ON users.business_id = businesses.business_id
JOIN addresses 
ON businesses.address_id = addresses.address_id
WHERE businesses.service_type = ?
AND addresses.country_iso = ?
```

I tried the following as well but still got an error:

```
SELECT username, users.business_id, businesses.latitude, businesses.longitude 
FROM users
JOIN businesses 
ON users.business_id = businesses.business_id
AND businesses.service_type = ?
JOIN addresses 
ON businesses.address_id = addresses.address_id
WHERE addresses.country_iso = ?
```

What is the right way to get the results I need?

Comment: And the exact error is?

Comment: Try to put the addresses table into your FROM part of the query

Comment: I get not error message.. The prepared statement just fails. When I try to print the error message, it returns blank.

Comment: @juergen d your comment was very helpful! It appears that I wasn't printing the error message correctly. Now I see that the "address_id" column in 'businesses' is actually called 'address'.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Juergen d's comment, I realized I wasn't printing the error message correctly.
I got the error message: 
Error: 1054 Unknown column 'businesses.address_id' in 'on clause'

So now I notice that the 'address_id' column is actually called 'address' in the 'business' table.